# What do you have to type into Password to display Correct?

Tags: python

I am new to python, and a friend of mine has given me this code.  I have searched up `\b` and `\r` and figured out that they're end-of-word character and return, respectively.  However, I have typed it exactly as `a` is, even copied on text editor, but it still says hat I failed. So, how exactly is `a` supposed to be typed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
a = "password \b\b\b\b\b " + "\b\b\b " + "\b\r "
b = "123456789"
c = "qwertyuiooo"
d = "sdfghjkl;"
e = "zxcvbnm,."
b = raw_input("Password: ")
if b == a:
  print("Correct")
else:
  print "YOUR A FAILURE!!!"
```

Comment: `\b` is a backspace, see [string literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringliteral).

Comment: *"YOUR A FAILURE"* "**You're** a failure."

Comment: I don't think any terminal is going actually send backspace characters to `raw_input()`; it'll send the resulting string *after applying backspace to it*. Your 'friend' is trolling you.

Comment: @NullUserException As if.

Comment: Actually, my friend broke the code and he admitted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martijn Pieters points out, most terminals won't send the `\b` character when you type backspace. So entering the password with the keyboard is not possible.

However, the keyboard is not your only option for entering data. You can also pipe in data from another file. Create a file which contains the password, `\b` and all:

```
file = open("thePassword.txt", "w")
file.write("password \b\b\b\b\b " + "\b\b\b " + "\b\r ")
file.close()
```

Then use `<` to pipe your password file into your friend's script.

```
C:\Users\AwesomeDude>myFriendsScript.py < thePassword.txt
Password: Correct
```

Comment: Oops, I always assume everyone is using Window's `cmd`, like me. I expect bash's format would look something like `echo thePassword.txt | myFriendsScript.py`, but it's been a long time since my last Unix session.

Comment: Its ok, I deleted last comment due to formatting issues, and tried but failed.  Tried your suggestion, and still failed.  The code may be broken.